# Example app in C that takes 2 positional parameters

Tags: c, bash, gcc, positional-operator

I am looking for an example of a simple app that will use `printf` to express two different strings based on a positional parameter.

In `bash` I would use:

```
case $1 in
    -h | --help )           showHelp
                            exit
                            ;;
    * )                     manPipe
                            exit 1
esac
```

And prior to this I would list that a function called `showHelp` would be called if the operater types either `$ foo -h` or `$ foo -help` into the Terminal. Anything else like `$ foo -bar` would request that the function `manPipe` would get called.

I have this code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

int secretFunction() {
    printf("Success! You found the secret message!");
}

int main() {

str posParam;
posParam = X;

printf("Enter a number:");
scanf("%s",&posParam);

if ( posParam == "X" ){
    printf("Welcome to app!\nType: " + $0 + " t\nto show a message");
}else{
    if (posParam == "t" ){
        secretFunction();
        }
return 0;
}
return 0;
```

I know this code is really crappy, I was trying to make an example of the above code in bash. I am not trying to convert a `bash script` into a `C app`, I'm trying to play around with it. I drew the idea of something I want to work on from the Wikipedia article on the [MD5 checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5) `C app` that takes a string and calculates the MD5 checksum for it. I cannot seem to work out what part they get the positional parameter to pass to the application.

This is a little different, I do understand, because it has prompted the user to provide an answer and then assign it to a value. I would rather use it as a positional parameter in the first instance.

Comment: So, I'm assuming from the language tags that `<cstring>` isn't the C++ standard library header for encompassing the C-equivalent `<string.h>`. Because in neither C nor C++ is `str` even a valid type provided by the standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `$1` in Bash (et al) is `argv[1]` in a C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        printf("You provided at least one argument (or parameter)\n");
        printf("The first argument is \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The argument `argc` is the number of valid entries in the `argv` array. `argv[0]` is the executable name, and you can access up to `argv[argc - 1]`. (Actually you can access `argv[argv]` as well, it is always a `NULL` pointer).

Comment: How do I specify `argv[x]`, where `x` is predetermined arguments, like `-k` and `-v` but anything else is considered garbage? Do you need an array to be predetermined with each `argv[]`, can I do `argv[-k,-v]` and then use `if (argv[1] == "-k") { do something;}` or will that not work?

Comment: @DanijelJ You don't. Just like in Bash you actually have to search for it. And you can't use `argv[1] == "-k"`, you have to use e.g. `strcmp(argv[1], "-k") == 0`. There are many example of argument parsing in C, and if you're on a POSIX platform (like Linux, BSD or OSX) then you can use the [`getopt`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) function to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As Joachim says, replace `$0` with `argv[0]`, also (assuming that str is a `char*`):

```
scanf("%s",&posParam);
           ^ there is no need to use &, posParam is already a pointer.
```

---

```
if ( posParam == "X" ){
```

strings can not be compared with `==`, instead use:

`if (strcmp(posParam, "X") == 0){`